# Do equivariant vector bundles always descend to the quotient?

Tags: general-topology, vector-bundles

Let $G$ be a topological group and $p:E\rightarrow X$ a $G$-equivariant topological vector bundle over the topological space $X$, where equivariant means that for any $v\in E$ and $g\in G$,

$$p(g\cdot v) = g\cdot p(v),$$

and $G$ acts between the fibres by linear isomorphisms. Then does this vector bundle always descend to a vector bundle over the topological space $X/G$ of $G$-orbits?

If not, what are the obstructions?

Cheers.

Comment: I think equivariance vector bundles generally require more than this -- in particular, I think you need to impose linearity of the action on the fibers at some stage.

Comment: Right, I should include that. Thanks.

Comment: Where does doing the obvious break?